# Catching exceptions in WebApp?

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

We're running a windows console app that's sending SignalR messages to multiple browsers through the SignalR backplane. We're doing this by hosting a SignalR server using OWN.WebApp:

```
public class SignalRWebApp : IDisposable
{
    public readonly string signalRUrl;
    private IDisposable webApp;

    public SignalRWebApp()
    {
        this.signalRUrl = String.Format("http://localhost:{0}", getFreePort());
        this.webApp = null;
    }

    private static int getFreePort()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
        listener.Start();
        var port = ((IPEndPoint) listener.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        listener.Stop();
        return port;
    }

    public bool started { get { return this.webApp != null; } }
    public void start(string signalRBackplaneConnectionString)
    {
        if (this.webApp != null)
            return;

        Action<IAppBuilder> startAction = app =>
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(signalRBackplaneConnectionString);
            app.MapSignalR();
        };

        this.webApp = WebApp.Start(this.signalRUrl, startAction);
    }

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~SignalRWebApp()
    {
        this.dispose(false);
    }

    private bool alreadyDisposed;

    protected virtual void dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.alreadyDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // dispose managed objects
                if (this.webApp != null)
                {
                    this.webApp.Dispose();
                    this.webApp = null;
                }
            }

            // free unmanaged objects
            // set large fields to null.

            this.alreadyDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Basically, we create a SignalRWebApp object, then call start(), passing it the connection string to the SqlServer backplane database. OWIN fires up a website in a background thread, and our code communicates with it through the signalRUrl (which is localhost with a dynamically allocated port number).

My problem: this is working in our dev and QA environments, but in our demo environment it's crashing without explanation.

I'm going through and trying to make sure that we at least catch and log any exception that might happen. And here's the thing - I can't see how to catch and log any exceptions that the OWIN WebApp might be throwing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event logs? If you don't catch an exception it normally appears there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log unhandled exceptions using the [AppDomain.UnhndledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It should capture any exception that's not handled by you.